# Why I can use initialtion list to construct object?

Tags: c++

I have a clsss which has three fields like

```
classA
{
  classA(float x, float y, float z) { _x = x; _y = y; _z = z;}
  float _x, 
  float _y,
  float _z
}
```

I used to use `ClassA a(1.0,2.0,3.0)` to construct object, now I found I can use

```
Class A = {1.0, 20.0, 3.0};
```

Is this a new feature in C++ 11?

Comment: `classA(float x, float y, float z) : _x { x }, _y { y }, _z { z } { }` is better.. (or ` : _x(x), _y(y), _z(z) { }` before C++11)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is called `Uniform Initialization`, it builds on initializer lists and tries to alleviate most vexing parse errors. Basically it is an initialization syntax that can be used on any object.

You can read more about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Uniform_initialization).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, C++ 11 expand the use of "{}" in initialization, and "=" could also be omitted.
Here are some examples:

```
int x={5};

double y {2.75};

short quar[3] {4,3,2};

int *p= new int [3] {2,3,5};   //c++ 11


ClassName a(3,15,6);//old style

ClassName a{3,15,6};//C++ 11

ClassName a={3,15,6};//C++ 11


vector<int> a3{4,6,1};
```